# Error sending email using EWS and a domain created at Godaddy

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, godaddy-api

I have a class for sending an email that uses the functions and properties of the EWS to do the service of reading boxes and sending an email. Using the `@hotmail.com` domain, I can read boxes and send emails normally. However, when I switch to my own domain created with GoDaddy, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: 'The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) .'
```

In both cases, the Url that I pass to the Exchange.WebService Url property is this: `https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx`. However, as previously mentioned, I can only send from my personal email (gustavo_martins1991@hotmail.com). From the email I have with GoDaddy (contato@uailivreart.com), I can't. I need help figuring out which Url I should configure for the email with the domain uailivreart.com. Can anyone help?

.

Comment: The FROM address and the email credential has to be from the same email account.  You also need to use a credential where the password is encrypted (not a user name and password).

Comment: As for the credentials, I'm using the same as the account. And always the email account (contato@uailivreart.com). The problem is in the url.

Comment: SMTP settings can be different on different email servers.  See : https://clean.email/blog/email-settings/godaddy-workspace-email-settings

Comment: I'd try using https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365 to test what your doing that should give you more information on what's happening and if it all configured correctly.